# How do you know what methods to use for a task?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I am learning Objective-C Cocoa programming for OS X, and object-based programming in general, so I am a big novice here, so my question is a bit general and my guess is the answer to this is simply "experience"; however, I am curious if there is some route of knowledge to understanding what methods in various classes are best or perhaps required for getting tasks done.

For example, in a programming guide I am instructed to create a document-based program, and the document class contains an array to store data, with the following method bound to a button to create a new entry in the array:

```
- (IBAction)insertItem:(id)sender {
    if (!theItems) {
        theItems = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    [theItems addObject:@"Double-click to edit."];

    [theTableView reloadData];

    [self updateChangeCount:NSChangeDone];
}
```

The array is "theItems" and its data is being presented in a TableView object. I understand that the steps here add a new string to the array and then refresh the table to display it, followed by setting the document to be set to an unsaved state.

What I am not getting is how one would know these specific steps and methods are required. Intuitively it seems one would just add items to the array, and that would be all that's required to have the new values simply show up in the table view for which the array is the data source, so how would one know that the tableView would need to be refreshed with the "reloadData" call? I can see someone (myself) figuring it out by trial and error, but is there some quick resource or guide (ie, some quick flow-chart) either in XCode or elsewhere that indicates for a table view that this would have to be a required action to display the new entry?

If I look at Apple's NSTableView class reference, it claims in the overview that you "modify the values in the data source and allow the changes to be reflected in the table view" which suggest the view is updated automatically, so the requirement to call "reloadData" on the view seems a little obscure.

Comment: To add...another such obscure feature here is that for this project you can double-click the table view to edit an entry once it has been added. While this is great, I never explicitly programmed it and cannot find anywhere that outlines this as a property of the table view, so figuring it out would simply be a trial and error approach. Had I not been told this by the programming guide, I'd have otherwise been looking for some method that would accept a mouse click (or something similar) to invoke this action...and essentially been lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the guides. In the [online class reference for `NSTableView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), there's a section at the top called "Companion Guides". For `NSTableView`, it lists the [Table View Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i). (In the prerelease 10.10 docs, the guides are listed under Related Documentation in the left-hand sidebar.)

I could have sworn this same information was available in Xcode's Documentation window, albeit somewhat hidden behind a "More related items" pseudo-link, but when I check right now there's no link to the guide anywhere in the `NSTableView` class reference. Which is a terrible oversight.

You can also browse or search the [Guides section of the developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Guides).

Comment: That's been my exact frustration, where the documentation does not show this, so it's a bit difficult to find the relevant methods. I know how to look them up ultimately, but often many seem redundant, or sometimes inapplicable. That's too bad there's no real resource for looking these details up, as it would help some folks find new ways of doing things far easier.

Answer (score 1):

Familiarity, studying the documentation and possibly reading some good books is the answer. For example, in the docs you quoted (emphasis mine)

> **you should** modify the values in the data source and allow the changes to be reflected in the table view

*You* should do both these things. If you want it to happen "automatically", look into [bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html), which uses several other Cocoa features you won't understand at this point either to do the table data source stuff for you. I'd recommend understanding what is happening manually before handing over control to bindings, so you have some chance of understanding when things go wrong.

As well as looking at the table view documentation, you also need to study the cell, delegate and datasource references. All of those objects work together to give you the functioning table view.